# Getting HTML from a div by excluding other divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, screen-scraping

We need to scrape the body of blog articles for our system (it's legit, I swear - we have a training blog and we want to display the content in help dialogs inside the system). The blogs are written on a 3rd party platform that produces HTML like so:

```
<div class="post">
    <h3 class="title">Title content</h3>

    <div class="byline">
        Byline content
    </div>

    <div class="submissions">
        Submission content
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
    </div>

    <p>Post body part 1</p>
    some more post body not in a tag, however the user enters it
    <p>Even more post body</p>

    <div class="tags">
        Tag content
    </div>      
</div>
```

I'm trying to get all the HTML content inside the post div, but excluding the title, byline, submissions, buttons, and tags sections.

If I run this jQuery:

```
$(".post").not(".title").not(".byline").not(".submissions").not(".buttons").not(".tags").html()
```

I get back the entire content of the post div, including the unwanted headers/divs. I've tried various incantations of not, including :not, and Googling until my eyes hurt, to no avail.

Any ideas? Seems like it should be pretty easy, so I'm guessing I'm missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the find method with :not like so

```
$('div.post').find(":not(.title,.byline,.submissions,.buttons,.tags)");
```

Season to taste.

The other option is to just hide the unwanted elements:

```
$('div.post').find('.title, .byline, .submissions, .buttons, .tags').hide();
```

Comment: This is much better than my solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're using selectors incorrectly.  Once it finds $(".post"), it will not look inside to exclude the content of that div.  $(".post") matches the selector precisely by not being title, byline, submissions, ad infinitum.

I suggest you target those other classes for removal and then grab html() or .post.

Make sense?

**EDIT: (Please don't vote me down without trying my method...it isn't great but it works)**

```
$(".title").remove();
$(".byline").remove();
$(".submissions").remove();
$(".buttons").remove();
$(".tags").remove();
alert($(".post").html());
```

Comment: you could just as easily do `$(".post").find(".title,.byline,.submissions,.buttons,.tags").remove();`

Comment: Yeah, I was in a race to redeem my reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to isolate that text using the `children()` method with a `:not` selector

```
$(".post").children(":not(.title,.byline,.submissions,.buttons,.tags)");
```

http://api.jquery.com/children/

or to totally isolate the content you want you could write:

```
var $cleansed = $(".post").clone();
$cleansed.find(".title,.byline,.submissions,.buttons,.tags").remove();

// append() or $cleansed.html() this content somewhere
```

Comment: This will only return the contents of the first child, right?

Comment: @Him - whoops, thought that inner text was within the `p` tag

Comment: @hunter Didn't mean that it was 100% flawed, it just didn't work properly when I tested it. :)